# Cloud function: No document found

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using cloud function to check if specific document exists but it did not work. No document found even there was. The code is below:

```
exports.onUserAppCreated = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/first_col/{colId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.data();

    const colId = data.colId;
    console.log(colId);
    var docRef = db.collection('users/{userId}/somecollection');

    let query = docRef.where('colId', '==', colId).get().then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {

            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            let tracksRef = db.collection('users/{userId}/othercolllection');
            tracksRef.where('otherId', '==', colId).get()
                                          .then(transSnapshot => {
                                            if (!transSnapshot.exists) {


                                                transSnapshot.ref.set({
                                                otherId: colId,
                                                time:admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                                                });
                                            }
                                            return transSnapshot;
                                          }).catch(error => {
                                                   console.log(error);
                                                   //response.status(500).send(error);
                                                })
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
            return;
        }
        return doc;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

Has I done something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to get the value of `colId` from the `{colId}` wildcard which is in the path `'users/{userId}/first_col/{colId}'`. You should use the [`context`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext.html) object as follows:

```
exports.onUserAppCreated = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/first_col/{colId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.data();

    const colId = context.params.colId;

    //....

});
```

Note that `snap` is the [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) corresponding to the document that triggered the Cloud Function. So `snap.data()` gives you an object containing **the fields** of this document, and therefore `data.colId` is undefined (unless you have saved the document id in a `colId` field in your document).

Note also that you could get the value of `colId` through the `snap` object by doing `snap.id`, but for the other wildcard, i.e. `userId`, you will need to use `context.params`.

---

**In addition,** note that you don't take into account the promises returned by the asynchronous methods of the Admin SDK (`get()`, `set()`). **It is very important** that you correctly return those promises, see the corresponding [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In fact, I managed to get the correct colId with snap.data(). I used this colId to search for a document in another collection using WHERE clause but it did not find the document though it exists. I then changed from 'doc.exist' to '!doc.empty' then it worked. However, when I tried to get data from document using 'doc.data()', it said doc.data is not a function. The same thing occured when I tried to insert new document into collection using something like 'transSnapshot.set(data)', it said 'transSnapshot.set' is not a function!

Comment: When you do `tracksRef.where('otherId', '==', colId).get()` you are creating a query and therefore, the snapshot you get is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) not a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot). You need to use `forEach` as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

Comment: Or, if you are 100% sure the query returns only one doc, you could also do `doc = transSnapshot.docs[0]`

Comment: Many thanks. If no document is found then I will need to insert new document to the current collection. How can I do that? I use "db.collection('users/{userId}/othercollection').doc(colId).set(new_doc)" but it did not work. No document was inserted! <code>

Comment: Yes, this should work, with new_doc being a map of the fields and values for the document. If you encounter anymore problem with this part of your code you may ask  anew question. If you think my answer gave you the solution to your initial problem, please accept it (by clicking on the 'check' button (like a v) next to the answer: When it turns green it means you accepted the answer.). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sure. Thanks!